# global.asax and ASP.NET MVC solution Organization

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, global-asax

I am refering to this article from [Jimmy Bogard](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2009/12/08/organizing-asp-net-mvc-solutions.aspx)

He is suggesting two projects to organize your ASP.NET MVC solution.

Basically, one project for the code and another for the rendering

My concern is about global.asax file.

Jimmy suggested separating global.asax from global.asax.cs and put them in two differents projects

When I did this, I could not compile my solution.

I got this error : *Could not load type 'MyProject.Web.Global'.*

Can someone help and show me how to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is so easy to reproduce the issue

- Create a new MVC2 application :Web.UI
- Add to the solution, a new class library type project : Web.Code
- Move from Web.UI to Web.Code the following:

  - Controllers
  - Models
  - Global.asax.cs
- In this second project, add a reference to

  - System.Configuration
  - System.Web
  - System.Web.Mvc
  - System.Web.ApplicationSewrvices
  - System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
  - System.Web.Routing

Compile and run

---

**UPDATE**

I found what was wrong

in global.asax file, I was not indicating the new namespace in the "inherits" attribute

```
   <%@ Application  Inherits="Project2.Global" Language="C#" %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing your code it is hard to guess what exactly the problem is.  When you create an MVC project the Global.asax markup has something like the following:

```
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="MyApp.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>
```

To put the Global.asax.cs in another project, you probably want to remove the CodeBehind="..." declaration from Global.asax and you have to change the Inherits="..." declaration to reference the correct namespace and classname as it is defined in Global.asax.cs.